# Shorter way to remove false values from a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

Presently I'm using `array_values(array_filter($arr))` to remove false values from an array.

It feels like there's most likely a built-in function that does this more tersely.

Comment: You can just use `array_filter($arr)` if you're okay with inconsistent key numbering (just use a `foreach` to loop instead). The only reason for `array_values` is simply to reset the keys.

Comment: Understood, the point is it seems like there ought to be a built in that does both of these at once. thx

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

```
function f($arr) {return array_values(array_filter($arr));}
```

Now you can do:

```
$b = f($a);
```

Much more terse! Much less readable.

`array_values(array_filter(..))` is very explicit as to what it does. This is many times more important than terseness.